# How to prove that $\frac{x^2}{yz+2}+\frac{y^2}{zx+2}+\frac{z^2}{xy+2}\geq \frac{x+y+z}{3}$ holds for any $(x,y,z)\in[1,2]^3$

Tags: inequality

Prove that for $x,y,z\in [1,2]$ the following inequality holds: $$\frac{x^2}{yz+2}+\frac{y^2}{zx+2}+\frac{z^2}{xy+2}\geq \frac{x+y+z}{3}.$$
I tried to apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality or the power mean inequality, but my attempts were unsuccessfull, so I am asking for help.

Comment: In order to avoid a massive amount of downvotes, please add your thoughts to the problems you propose.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio where did you learnt inequalitites

Comment: @Aditya: I found the "Cauchy-Schwarz master class" by M.Steele and "Algebraic inequalities" by V.Cirtoaje two very interesting books. Also "Secrets in inequalities" by Pham Kim Hung is very interesting. Do you agree to try reopening this question in order to propose our solutions?

Answer (score 3):

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{2+yz}\geq\frac{\left(\sum_{cyc} x\right)^2}{\sum_{cyc}(2+yz)},\tag{1}$$
hence we just need to prove that, over the given domain: 
$$\sum_{cyc}x \geq 2+\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}yz \tag{2}$$
that is equivalent to:
$$x(3-y)+y(3-z)+z(3-x)\geq 6.\tag{3}$$
By setting $x=\frac{3+u}{2},y=\frac{3+v}{2},\frac{3+w}{2}$, proving $(3)$ is equivalent to proving:
$$ uv+vw+uw\leq 3\tag{4}$$
for $u,v,w\in[-1,1]$. But $(4)$ is trivial.

Comment: Could you explain please how you got (2)? Thanks.

Comment: @AlexeyRyabukhin: You need that the RHS of (1) is greater than $\frac{x+y+z}{3}$. Just rearrange ;)

Comment: @user109899: $u=2x-3$. Also note that (2) can be strengthened to $$t\ge 2+ \frac{t^2}{9}$$ for $t\in[3,6]$ which is also trivial.